# Как сделать отступ у scrollbar сверху и снизу?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Как сделать отступ у scrollbar сверху и снизу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ. Нужно `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` задать `margin`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Что здесь можно подробнее написать? Пишешь ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{margin: 10px 0px;} и всё